# How can we use the Editable table feature in combination with the angular-datepicker component?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, x-editable

How can we use the Editable table feature in combication the angular-datepicker component.
http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table

In the above link, lets say one of my field is a Date, how can I implement it ? I know there is this bsdate thing, but somehow it doesn't work inside a table.

http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#bsdate

Comment: have you got a fix for this. I am facing similar issue. Datepicker pop up comes but has no effect of changed date and takes default.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this fix was merged 4 days ago. Here is the thread :
https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/pull/258

And it was just released 12 hours ago. It works with the new Version 
https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/releases/tag/0.1.9